Did commoners call their masters m'Lord in the past?
In Game of Thrones S02E07 when Arya Stark calls Tywin Lannister my Lord, he corrects her:

Tywin Lannister: Girl, m'Lord. Low-born girls say m'Lord, not my Lord. If you're going to pose as a commoner, you should do it properly.

I have searched the internet but found nothing historical.

This is an in-universe statement; do we have any reason to doubt that he's speaking the truth about what he's observed? What might or might not have been the case in our universe isn't relevant

@AakashM I don't try to debunk Tywin's lines. I just am curious if there are real examples in the past

If you're asking about the real world past, then how is this question related to Game of Thrones (and why is this posted on M&TV and why are you using the 'realism' tag)?

Please migrate this question to Skeptics website.

In England, certainly it has precedent.
Variations of "milord" or "m'lord" or "m'lud" depending on region and pronunciation.
Women of high status would be referred to as "Milady". Such Lady Penelope :)



Wikipedia
Previously, judges were addressed as "Milord" but this has altered in the recent past.

"Milord" (in this use generally pronounced as, and sometimes written as, "M'lud": /məˈlʌd/) is not used in legal settings in the United Kingdom anymore, instead the form of address for several types of judges is just "My Lord


I’m not sure if this answers the question. I think the question is about whether it’s realistic for there to be a class difference between “my lord” and “m’lord”.
